# How to use jquery to select all elements that have two specific attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some markup where a lot of id's have an id attribute, as well as innerText. I want to select each of these elements, performing a function on the id.

How do I do that?

Comment: What is the `innerText` attribute? Do you just mean that the elements *contain* text?

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of id's" and "performing a function on the id". Examples would be helpful.

Comment: @Felix: Yes, i mean the elements contain text. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If you could give us a markup sample it would go a long way.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I meant there exist some 50 (?) elements which have an id. I would like to look at one of those elements at a time, and call processid(element.id).

Comment: @Joshua, tell me:  Are the element id's repeated or unique?  If they are repeated your document is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('[id]:not(:empty)').each(function(i, el) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a common class:

#### HTML

```
<div id="first" class="all"></div>
<div id="second" class="all"></div>
<div id="third" class="all"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('div.all').each(function(index){
    processid(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First select by a regular ID selector and then loop over that selection by filtering .text() non-empty.

```
$("[id]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This insinuates that the selector would return more than one result when selecting by ID, which insinuates that the document has more than one element with the same ID.  That is invalid, and will cause problems.

Comment: No it doesn't. .each() works, even if the selector is a single element. Besides, this snippet will work, even if the asker decides to switch to classes or names.

Comment: ".each() works, even if the selector is a single element." Affirmative.  However, if you are trying to argue that you *intended* to select *only one element* and "iterate" over that single element, then I can't take you seriously.

Comment: Busted :) I quickly came up with an answer not thinking of the consequences of "ID".

Comment: This selects an element with id set to id. OP wants to select all the elements with an id. wombleton has the right idea

Comment: I completely misunderstood his question! I edited my solution, but wombleton's is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about selecting elements whose id  (*or some permutation of it*) is included in its text then

```
$('[id]').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().indexOf( this.id ) >= 0; // the this.id should be altered to match the permutation you seek ..
}).css('color','red'); // turn those to red
```

---

After you comment to @lonesomeday (*at the question comments*) here is what to do ..

```
$('[id]').each(function(){
  processid(this.id);
});
```